# PrimeFaces - Selecionar linha DataTable via JQuery, Javascript ou PF

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsf, primefaces

Como faço para selecionar uma linha de um DataTable, utilizando o JQuery, Javascript puro ou o o comando javascript PF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Obs: Não é uma solução muito elegante, mas resolve seu problema.**

Você pode selecionar diretamente uma coluna na linha desejada da datatable via jQuery e então chamar o evento .click()

Exemplo:

```
$('#form\\:singleDT_data tr[data-ri=4] td').click()
```

Explicando:

Primeiramente você seleciona a datatable via jQuery `$('#form\\:singleDT_data)` (não esquecer de escapar os dois pontos com barra barra (\\:).

Depois seleciona uma linha da table usando o atributo data-ri e passando o index como argumento:`$('#form\\:singleDT_data tr[data-ri=4])`.

Por fim, seleciona um elemento de coluna do resultado e chama o .click() `$('#form\\:singleDT_data tr[data-ri=4] td').click()`.

Você pode testar esta solução diretamente no [Showcase do PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml)

O exemplo indicado irá selecionar a linha 5 da datatable "Single with Row Click".